# (Android) Set Width/Height of (Image-)Button in Java Class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to set the `width` and `height` of an `ImageButton` in the `Java Class`, the width of the button should be the `width of the display / 4`, the height of the button should be the `height of the display / 4`.

**Code:**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;

        ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        // button.setWidth(width/4)
        // button.setHeight(height/4)
    }
```

Apparently there's **no** method for a button called `setWidth()` or `setHeight()`, so how can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible weight is what are you looking for. For example this code will give you four rectangles, everyone takes quarter of a screen

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

You can define weightSum in linearlayout and views will be scaled to be percent of weightSum.

Answer (score 0):

Not letting me comment but if you look in the activity_main.xml, you should find something like this in it.

```
<ImageButton
android:contentDescription="@+id/imageButton1"
android:id="@+id/imageButton1" />
```

from here, you can add into this `android:layout_width = 50p`, where 50p is 50 pixels wide. You can change this to `android:layout_height = 100p, just change the 50 and 100 to numbers of your liking. so, it would look like this after you add them in,

```
<ImageButton
android:contentDescription="@+id/imageButton1"
android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
android:layout_width ="50p"
android:layout_height ="50p" />
```

Comment: thats how i did it but im not sure if it will resize it accordingly based on the difference of sizes of screens or if that just sets it as being that for all screens.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the width and height of the ImageView from Java code you can do something like this:

```
LayoutParams params = button.getLayoutParams();
params.width = width/4;
params.height = height/4;
button.requestLayout();
```